# About Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question related to Pandas.

In df1 I have a data frame with the id of each seller and their respective names.

In df2 I have the id of the salesmen and their respective sales.

I would like to have in the df2, two new columns with the first name and last names of the salesmen.

PS. in df2 one of the sales is shared between two vendors.

```
import pandas as pd

vendors = {'first_name': ['Montgomery', 'Dagmar', 'Reeba', 'Shalom', 'Broddy', 'Aurelia'],
         'last_name': ['Humes', 'Elstow', 'Wattisham', 'Alen', 'Keningham', 'Brechin'],
         'id_vendor': [127, 241, 329, 333, 212, 233]}

sales = {'id_vendor': [['127'], ['241'], ['329, 333'], ['212'], ['233']],
         'sales': [1233, 25000, 8555, 4333, 3222]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(vendors)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

I attach the code. any suggestions?`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you want the result? in a list as well like the ids? Please add the expected output

Comment: I would like df2 to be like this: https://prnt.sc/KDvFnyVlYI9Z

Comment: Is sales really having a list of strings in `id_vendors`? Because id_vendor in `vendors` is integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `df1` with `df2` with the [exploded](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) `id_vendors` column and use [`DataFrame.GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) when grouping by `sales` to obtain the columns as you want:

```
transform_names = lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))

res = (df1.merge(df2.explode('id_vendor')).
       groupby('sales').
       agg({'first_name': transform_names, 'last_name': transform_names, 
            'id_vendor': list})
      )

print(res)
```

```
          first_name        last_name   id_vendor
sales                                            
1233      Montgomery            Humes       [127]
3222         Aurelia          Brechin       [233]
4333          Broddy        Keningham       [212]
8555   Reeba, Shalom  Wattisham, Alen  [329, 333]
25000         Dagmar           Elstow       [241]
```

### Note:

In your example, `id_vendors` in `df2` is populated by lists of strings, but since `id_vendor` in `df1` is of integer type, I assume that it was a typo. If `id_vendors` is indeed containing lists of strings, you need to also convert the strings to integers:

```
transform_names = lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))

# Notice the .astype(int) call.
res = (df1.merge(df2.explode('id_vendor').astype(int)).
       groupby('sales').
       agg({'first_name': transform_names, 'last_name': transform_names, 
            'id_vendor': list})
      )

print(res)
```